# WCF Service with MSMQ Binding Endpoint Configuration Issue

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, msmq

Been looking for a solution to this problem for several days now and can't quite find a solution to my exact problem.  Basically, I've got a WCF service that I wrote and I'm using an MSMQ binding on it.  Had it working fine locally, but when I'm moving it to my server, I'm having some issues.  Here's my setup ( This is all running on a Windows Server 2012 box):  I've got a site set up (**not** the default site) with both Http, Https and net.msmq bindings added.  The DefaultSite also has net.msmq bindings added as well - if that makes a difference.  The site is assigned to an AppPool running under an AD account.  The site is named app.services and is host-headered as dev.app.services.domain.  I've got a Private transactional queue created called queueservice\queuelogservice.svc. I've got a ton of permissions set on my queue (Anonymous Login, my AD account, the AD account that the app pool is running under, Network Service account, local admin account, etc - all with full control).  My msmq endpoint is net.msmq://dev.app.services.domain/private/QueueService/QueueLogService.svc.  The url that I'm trying to test this by pulling up the wcf service in IE is http://dev.app.services.domain/QueueService/QueueLogService.svc.

When I had the WCF service deployed to the default site, it works fine. But when I deploy it to my app.services site, all I'm getting is the "Access Denied" error: "*An error occurred while opening the queue:Access is denied. (-1072824283, 0xc00e0025). The  message cannot be sent or received from the queue. Ensure that MSMQ is installed and running. Also ensure that the queue is available to open with the required access mode and authorization.* "

I've read the articles "MSMQ, WCF and IIS: Getting them to play nice" parts 1-3 by Tom Hollander (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-1/) and that was great, but it didn't tell me anything about how to set this up under a different site other than localhost.  I'm sure I'm just missing something simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I read that I may need to rename my queue to match my site name (app.services\queueservice\queuelogservice.svc), but that didn't work.  Didn't work with naming it with the host name either (dev.app.services.domain\queueservice\queuelogservice.svc).  I've played with a lot of combinations, but no dice.  I either get really nasty errors, or end up with this access denied issue.  My expectation is that I can see the standard QueueLogService page in IE like I do when I run this locally.

Any ideas on what I could be missing?

Here's the config for my WCF service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="Separator" value="*"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="QueueService.QueueLogService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://dev.app.services.domain/QueueService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        <endpoint address="net.msmq://dev.app.services.domain/private/QueueService/QueueLogService.svc" binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBinding" contract="QueueService.IQueueLogService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="dev.app.services.domain" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="myBinding">
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </netMsmqBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Secure">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false `enter code here`before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: To open up the queue for testing I add just "everyone" and "anonymous logon" full control to cover all the bases.

Comment: Is the "working fine locally" machine part of the domain like the server?

Comment: Yes, my dev box is in the same domain.  I've already got "everyone" and" anonymous logon" in there having full control.  Locally, all I had to do was add my AD account, since that's the account that my IIS application was running under.  Also, I should mention that on my site in IIS, the Binding Information is set to dev.app.services.domain - I've seen instructions to set that as localhost, but I figured that was only at the default site level.  Not sure if that's another problem or not.